# Test Install4j rollback in upgrade

Tags: java, install4j

I am implementing silent upgrade using "Updater without version check" of install4j. For negative scenario I want to test whether rollback in any failure case is working or not. So somehow I want to explicitly fail the upgrade and test the rollback is working or not.

So is there any way to explicitly fail the upgrade and test the rollback? Either in build install4j method or some other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a "Run script" action at the desired point of failure with a script of

```
false
```

and set its failure strategy to "Quit on failure".